# log not showing during boot, even with: debug nosplash --verbose

Tags: boot, kernel, log

this is the whole custom line I boot with:

linux   /vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic udev.event-timeout=5 root=/dev/mapper/LvmMyGroup-mywhatever ro debug nosplash $vt_handoff --verbose

this is the latest kernel
this problem is happening since a long time tho, I think since kernel 5.4 or earlier...
I use that timeout because on earlier kernels it was taking 6 minutes just to boot. Not sure if needed now tho but causes no harm.

am I doing something wrong?

Also, I want to see the log DURING the boot time, not after. So that if it takes too long to boot, I can have some clue what the problem is.

Btw, if I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del just after it starts loading that boot entry, and let the boot happen again, it will show the log, that is the most weird thing. I did not test this with the latest kernel tho, as it is already failing to work as expected from the beginning.

Comment: Are you sure that `/dev/mapper/LvmMyGroup-mywhatever` (assumed to be LVM) exists when `grub` tries to boot? Isn't LVM set up later in the boot process?

Comment: Only these `insmod part_gpt; insmod ext2` happen before that line, there is nothing about lvm there also. I dont know how it works, but my guess is that it happens later, any way to be sure? Also why something that is already loaded (vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic) would depend on the lvm driver to show a log? I mean, there is things happening that are unrelated to the lvm and could be logged from the beggining. Btw, if I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del just after it starts loading and let the boot happen again, it will show the log, that is the most weird thing.